# request querystring code behind

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, query-string

How do I request the querystring for an .vb page.

I have tried request.querystring("test") but that says request is not declared.

and

System.Web.HttpContext.Current.request.querystring("test") - that doesnt show any errors but does not work when I try to write it in a variable then to the page

I am trying to request the querystring through a .vb file in the app_code folder.

Comment: When you redirect from one page to another ex. www.test.com/text.aspx?id=1. the request.querystring("id") will bring you 1

Comment: I know how to request querystring on the front end of a page eg request.querystring("test"). I'm fine with that, but just stuck how to request on a .vb page

Comment: "when I try to write it in a variable then to the page" - can you show us your code?

Comment: if isnumeric(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.request.querystring("test")) then
dbcomm1.parameters.add("@test", System.Web.HttpContext.Current.request.querystring("test"))
end if  That is what I need to work ultimately but I tried response.write(test) to see if it pulled through any value